# How can I pass this id variable?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to pass this id

```
<img id="id_<?php echo $post_id;?>">
```

in  "here"

```
req.open('GET','post.php?slug=??here??',true);
```

each id  is different so I need to target the "id" of  every post .Now how can I pass the id

Comment: `<img class="myTarget" data-id="<?php echo $post_id;?>">` may be more easy -> select all 'myTarget', and retrieve the id from the data attribute.

Comment: Well that's totally depends, how you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty vague, but are you thinking about something like this?

```
<a href='post.php?slug=<?=$post_id?>'>
  <img id="id_<?php echo $post_id;?>">   
</a>
```

Comment: no i dont need it on  href ......... i need something  like federkun  did